# Growing memory allocation as WPF application navigates

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I am building a WPF application and have been trying to implement opening a new page when a button is clicked.

The button is in the page MainPage and it opens the page SafetySettings. There is then a button in the SafetySettings page which opens the MainPage.

The only way I have been able to open the pages successfully is with the following:

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SafetySettings safety = new SafetySettings();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SafetySettings),safety);
    }
```

This works as desired but I noticed the memory allocation of the program continuously increases as I swap between the pages.  I think I am not implementing this correctly but I could not figure out another way to open a new page from the current page.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace DataAcquisitionGUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SafetySettings safety = new SafetySettings();
            this.Frame.Content = null;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SafetySettings),safety);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your memory allocation is growing cause you create SafetySettings new each time you click the button and I think you do not dispose the item correctly so there is no clean-up.
Implement the IDisposable interface in your SafetySettings or create a method which "destroys" the instance of your class. This helps you to keep your application clean of unused resources!

Comment: That makes sense, but I am just confused because I don't see any information on implementing IDisposable or destroy methods in Page classes.  Do you know of any resources I could look at to research this option?

Comment: Please look at this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: I ended up using a navigation panel element to navigate between the pages rather than buttons.  This seems to implement garbage collection on its own is now working well. Thanks!